# Tableau viz embedded in IPython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, tableau-api

I have published a Tableau 9.3 viz on Tableau public:
https://public.tableau.com/profile/michel.page#!/vizhome/exercice1/Courbesventesetprofit

I have succedded to have this viz displayed in a web page by integrating the code given by the 'Share' button on the Tableau public viz page.

Now I want to do the same, but inside an IPython notebook. It seems to be possible because I saw an example in nbviewer here: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/msund/96bd1d837f4139b2558d

I have integrated  the 'Share' button script code into a Markdown cell but the viz won't get displayed when the cell is run. When I look at the browser console, it seems that the js code, and object tag get sanitized, even if I tell IPython to trust the notebook.

Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the Tableau viz to show up in your Jupyter notebook, Use the %%HTML magic in a normal cell:

```
%%HTML

<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1474058356757' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='#'><img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;ex&#47;exercice1&#47;Courbesventesetprofit&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='site_root' value='' /><param name='name' value='exercice1&#47;Courbesventesetprofit' /><param name='tabs' value='yes' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;ex&#47;exercice1&#47;Courbesventesetprofit&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1474058356757');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    vizElement.style.width='100%';vizElement.style.height=(divElement.offsetWidth*0.75)+'px';                    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>
```

This is a great resource on what else you can do with magics: https://blog.dominodatalab.com/lesser-known-ways-of-using-notebooks/

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is this

step 1) copy the java script tag from Tableau workbook

[image]

step 2) Go and add the code in your jupyter cell code as below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Compared with R and Python, Tableau is a much faster way for data visualization. The best practice I can come up with is to **set size to automatic** when you create in tableau, share it on Tableau Public, and put the embed code like the following after you publish.

```
%%HTML
<Embed Code Here>
```

Look for example here:
https://www.kaggle.com/andyxie/tableau-sharing-best-practice/